# Problems regarding White Screen Of Death (WSOD) at my site

Tags: iis, windows-server-2019, wsod

I have a problem regarding White Screen Of Death (WSOD) at my site.
I will try to explain what I have tried until now.

I know it is not a triviel error to debug, but maybe some of you have tried something similar.

Here is the setup: One Windows Server 2019 v1809 with one IIS: 10.0.17763.1.
Multiple websites with associated application pools.
It's a MVC solution, and we are using .net 4.7.2.

What I have tried:

- Recycled application pools every night
- Restarted the server every night
- Issued a IISReset every night
- Deleted temporary files in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\
- Looked at the IIS logs
- Looked at the application log, our own log
- Looked at the Windows log
- Searched the Internet for similar problems
- Made sure there always were some traffic at the website
- Made sure no errors were shown when pressing F12 in the browser, the site always returs code 200

The WSOD comes at varies times, and not all the sites are affected at the same time.
A manuel recycle of the website always helps.

My question is, have any of you encounted similar problems?
And how did you solve it?

If you need more information please ask, and I will try to provide it.

/Regards Søren

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem is very unusual in IIS, because there is almost no record and useful information in the log file.

You can try to use this plan to repair IIS.

1. Unregister all the versions of ASP.NET with command "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis –ua". and the framework 64 also versions. 3.0 and 3.5... etc
2. Delete  ASPNET account from "Local Users and Group – Users".
3. reregister ASP.NET  with IIS using "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis –i". and framework64... net 3, 3.5 etc
4. Give permissions to the ASPNET account using "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis –ga machinename\ASPNET". for framework 32 and 64 and versions.
5. Reset IIS .